# Build a Discord bot that Tweets

Tags: javascript, twitter, discord, bots

I've been tasked with creating a bot which can create a tweet when someone posts in a Discord server. I've not been able to find any documentation out there aside from Twitter -> Discord bots. But it's clearly doable, as the site https://www.Zapier.com seems to offer exactly that.

I've been using discord.js and node.js for my projects so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
// Discord Modules
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.js')

// Express for the Heroku fix
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Hook up to the server as a user
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

// Create a collection of available commands
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    // set a new item in the Collection
    // with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


// Listen for incoming chat commands, and compare them to the collection.
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

  if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
  
  if (command.args && !args.length) {
    return message.channel.reply(`You didn't provide any arguments`)
  }

  try {
    command.execute(message, args)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
  }
})


  //For avoidong Heroku $PORT error
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var result = 'App is running'
    response.send(result);
}).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('App is running, server is listening on port ', app.get('port'));
});

client.login(token)
```

And the command to call in order to post a tweet

```
// Twitter Modules
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('../config');
const T = new Twit(config);

module.exports = {
  name: 'tweet',
  description: 'create a tweet from a discord post',
  execute(message, args) {
    let discPost = args
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: discPost }, tweeted)
  }
}

// Make sure it worked!
function tweeted (err, reply) {
  if (err !== undefined) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('Tweeted: ' + reply)
  }
}
```

Ugly little proof of concept, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for replying to your own question which is bothering me for weeks. I am trying to build an IoT project and wanted to find out how the notification works. My experience is similar to yours, only able to find solutions on sending messages to Discord but not the other way around. I will give this a try, thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Note I've got my 0Auth tokens for discord and twitter in a config file, thats all that isn't showing.